# how to get default checked value by using imploded data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, explode, laravel-8

In a create post form i have store the data into database using implode function because data was in array

```
$this->posts->optional_info = implode(" ",$input['optional_info']);
```

now In edit form i want the data stored in database should get checked by default in view

so i am trying like

```
<div class="row">
         @foreach($customArray['optional'] as $key => $value)
         <div class="col-md-4 pl-1 pr-1 col-6">
          <div class="cstm-check pos-rel">
              <input type="checkbox" name="optional_info[]" 
             {{old('optional_info[]',explode(" ",$posts->optional_info)) == $key ? 'checked' : ''}}  
               value="{{$value}}" id="{{ __($key) }}" />
               <label for="{{ __($key) }}" class="">{{ __($value) }}</label>
          </div>
         </div>
         @endforeach
```

where  $customArray['optional'] contain

```
'optional'=>[
        'FLOATER'=>'Floater', 
        'DROP_IN'=>'Drop In', 
        'CUTBACK'=>'Cutback', 
        'AIR'=>'Air', 
        'BARREL_ROLL'=>'Barrel Roll', 
        'SNAP'=>'Snap',
        '360'=>'360',
        'WIPEOUT'=>'Wipeout',
    ],
```

i just want that the values should explode and compair to each key and get checked when true.please help me out. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would be something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach($customArray['optional'] as $key => $value)
    <div class="col-md-4 pl-1 pr-1 col-6">
        <div class="cstm-check pos-rel">
            <input type="checkbox" name="optional_info[]" 
            {{ (in_array($key, old('optional_info[]', explode(" ",$posts->optional_info))) ? 'checked' : '' }}
            value="{{$value}}" id="{{ __($key) }}" />
            <label for="{{ __($key) }}" class="">{{ __($value) }}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```